# get values from a dictionary using a list of indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-manipulation

Given a list:

```
x = [0.0, 0.87, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.32, 0.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I want to get the indexes of all the values that are not 0 and store them in `d['inds']`
Then using the indexes in `d['inds']` go through the list of `x` and get the values.
So I would get something like:

```
d['inds'] = [1, 5, 6, 9]
d['vals'] = [0.87, 0.32, 0.46, 0.10]
```

I already got the indexes using:

```
d['inds'] = [i for i,m in enumerate(x) if m != 0]
```

but I'm not sure how to get `d['vals']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d['vals'] = [x[i] for i in d['inds']]
```

Better yet, do both at once:

```
vals = []
inds = []
for i,v in enumerate(x):
    if v!=0:
        vals.append(v)
        inds.append(i)
d['vals']=vals
d['inds']=inds
```

or

```
import numpy as np
d['inds'],d['vals'] = np.array([(i,v) for i,v in enumerate(x) if v!=0]).T
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `numpy`, its indexing features are designed for tasks like this one:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0.0, 0.87, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.32, 0.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10, 0.0, 0.0])

x[x!=0]
Out: array([ 0.87,  0.32,  0.46,  0.1 ])
```

and if you're still interested in the indices:

```
np.argwhere(x!=0)
Out: 
array([[1],
       [5],
       [6],
       [9]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
m = {i:j for i,j in enumerate(x) if j!=0}

list(m.keys())
Out[183]: [1, 5, 6, 9]

list(m.values())
Out[184]: [0.87, 0.32, 0.46, 0.1]
```

if you want to save this in a dictionary `d` then you can do:

```
d = {}
d['vals']=list(m.values())

d['ind']=list(m.keys())
d
  {'vals': [0.87, 0.32, 0.46, 0.1], 'ind': [1, 5, 6, 9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Pandas:

```
x = [0.0, 0.87, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.32, 0.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10, 0.0, 0.0]
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(x)
inds = data[data[0]!=0.0].index
print(inds)
```

**Output: Int64Index([1, 5, 6, 9], dtype='int64')**

Answer (score 1):

Much easier:

```
df['vals']=list(filter(None,x))
df['idx']=df['vals'].apply(x.index)
```

#### Exaplantion:

1. Use `filter(None,x)` for filtering non-0 values, (`None` basically neans no statement (or not `False`)
2. Then use pandas apply for getting the index basically go trough the `'vals'` column then then get the values index in the list `x`